# is there any possiblities to convert html to pdf using jquery in cordova angular js wnd uwp app?I received 'blob:ms-appx-web' not allowed to load

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g6Qw.png)

[image]

I received

> **SEC7134: Resource 'blob:ms-appx-web://mysiteurl/3d5c0f51-04e2-4944-bf3e-4ea19185511c' not allowed to load**

this type of error. So please help us to solve this issue.

**Here my script code**:

```
function GeneratePdf() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world');
    doc.text(20, 20, "Hello world from the angular js");

    //var blobpdf = new Blob([doc.output('blob')], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    //var bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blobpdf);
    doc.save('document.pdf');
    var blobPDF = new Blob([doc.output()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF); 

    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
       window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobUrl);
    }
    else {
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);
        //download(objectUrl)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some solution, i have no idea about that but i have worked on a simple php library which converts the whole html code into corresponding pdf including images and style. Named 'dompdf'
I know this is not the solution you are looking for but i think it may help you or other.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i'll try by this concept.

Answer (score 0):

yes, dompdf or you can use Fpdf library.

Comment: This is angular js with litesql. Here we cant use php code

Comment: As per your comment , you need to use any server language like php or any other. So if you choose php then dompdf is there for u